# multithreading and hibernate entity id generator

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, oracle, hibernate

Recently, i have converted my entities to be portable.
We  like that  our entities can be use with oracle database and mysql(Before it's only oracle).
Before, to generate an entity id,  we use SequenceGenerator and now we have changed to GenericGenerator.

Old code :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_1")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_1", sequenceName = "SEQ_1",  allocationSize = 1)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

New code :

```
@GenericGenerator(name="SEQ_1", strategy="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters={
        @Parameter(name="sequence_name",value="SEQ_1"),
        @Parameter(name="optimizer",    value="seqhilo"),
        @Parameter(name="initial_value",value="1"),
        @Parameter(name="increment_size",value="1")
    })
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

And My problem is that, we have many exception on entities creation when we work on multithreading.
We use 3.3.2 of version Hibernate.

Comment: what kind of error code you're getting?

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
......
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST_PK) violated
....
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000. Note that, with the old code, all works fine.

Comment: It's strange, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10069723/836215 you still should use sequence in backgroung

Comment: I suspect that using org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator is not thread safe.

Comment: I have detected the problem, with code  @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "seqHilo") we use as optimizer NoopOptimizer and it's not thread safe. Optimizer for seqHilo does not exists in my hibernate version and it take the default optimizer is NoopOptimizer.